# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-x)^{\frac{\log(1+\frac{x^2}2)}{\sin^5x}}$ without the use of the Hôpital's rule and asymptotics $\sim_0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-x)^{\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}2\right)}{\sin^5x}} \tag 1$$

With the Hôpital's rule written with the form

$$e^{g(x)\log f(x)}$$

I will have the indeterminate form $\left(\frac00\right)$ if $x\to 0$. I have thinked to write the $(1)$ as:

$$\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{-\frac 1x}\right)\right]^{-\frac 1x}\to e$$ with $t=-1/x$. Infact if $x\to 0 \implies t\to \infty$.
Considering only the exponent, I will have
$$ \frac{-x\log(1+x^2/2)}{\sin^5 x}=\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{-\log(1+x^2/2)}{\sin^4x}\to_0 \quad 1\cdot \frac00$$

and I think now that this way it is not correct. Is there another mode to solve the $(1)$? At this moment I have not another idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By standard limits we have that

$$\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}2\right)}{\sin^5x}\log(1-x)=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}2\right)}{\frac{x^2}2}\frac{x^5}{\sin^5x}\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\frac{1}{2x^2}\to -\infty $$

therefore

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-x)^{\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}2\right)}{\sin^5x}}=0 $$

Comment: Hi, you have used $e^{g(x)\log f(x)}$. :-) Why using Symbolab I have seen that diverges? Probaby I can do mistakes...as usual :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%281-x%29%5E%28%28log%281%2Bx%5E2%2F2%29%29%2Fsin%5E5x%29+as+x+to+0) agrees with the convergence at $0$. Also the evaluation by standard limits is pretty straightforward. You could check again your input.

Comment: Who knows what I will have written. Boh :-(

Comment: Now it is solved! Bye :)

Comment: Thank you very much $1^\infty$ that is an indeterminate form :-)

Comment: Hi, excuse me very much. Why the limit $\to-\infty$? $\frac{\log (1-x)}{-x}\to -1$?

Comment: Isn’t it the limit for $x\to0$?

Comment: Yes of course...just for the exponent into your steps, where you write $\to-\infty$.

Comment: Since $\ln(1-x)/x\to -1$.

Comment: Thank you very much again.